# AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute

Tags: python, button, kivy, attributeerror, kivy-language

I try to bind a function (in .py) to button (in kv.) after directory selection with Filechooser (all at one Screen) as follows:

.py:

```
class SyllWindow(Screen): #screen where all happens

    def select(self, *args):

        if args[1]:

            filepath = args[1][0]

            try: self.label.text = filepath

            except: pass

    def output_csv(corpus_root): #function

        corpus = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, '.*') #this must be irrelevant actually
        def reduce_dip(corpus_string):
            corpus_string = corpus_string.replace("Ei", "ö")
            corpus_string = corpus_string.replace("ei", "ö")
            # reduced
            corpus_string = corpus_string.replace("ie", "ö")
            return corpus_string
        vowels = [' ','a','e','i','o','u','ä','ö','ü','A','E','I','O','U','Ä','Ö','Ü']
        cfd_syll = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(
            (textname, num_syll)
            for textname in corpus.fileids()
            for num_syll in [len(w) for w in ''.join(char for char in reduce_dip(corpus.raw(fileids=textname)) if char in vowels).split()])
        syll_dataframe = DataFrame(cfd_syll)
        return syll_dataframe.to_csv(path + '\silben.csv')            

    pass
```

.kv (button block):

```
Button:

                            text: '.csv'
                            font_size: 14
                            on_release: self.output_csv(self.filepath)
```

Looks like this:

[image]

After pressing ".csv" I get an error `AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'output_csv'`
I'm aware of similar issues described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50426891/attributeerror-button-object-has-no-attribute-scrlfbtn), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789280/attributeerror-object-has-no-attribute) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49258892/attributeerror-object-has-no-attribute), but all examples there are in Python language, while my issue seems to be more about Kivy language.

I'd be grateful for any advice.

Full error traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
  "__main__", mod_spec)
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
  exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\GUI Projects\gercort\main.py", line 147, in <module>
  Gercort().run()
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 855, in run
  runTouchApp()
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
  EventLoop.window.mainloop()
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
  self._mainloop()
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
  EventLoop.idle()
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 342, in idle
  self.dispatch_input()
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 327, in dispatch_input
  post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 293, in post_dispatch_input
  wid.dispatch('on_touch_up', me)
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\kivy\_event.cp37-win32.pyd", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 179, in on_touch_up
  self.dispatch('on_release')
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\kivy\_event.cp37-win32.pyd", line 703, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\kivy\_event.cp37-win32.pyd", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\kivy\_event.cp37-win32.pyd", line 1098, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 64, in custom_callback
  exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
File "C:\GUI Projects\gercort\gercort.kv", line 489, in <module>
  on_release: self.output_csv(self.filepath2)
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\kivy\weakproxy.cp37-win32.pyd", line 32, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__

builtins.AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'output_csv'
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: @KlausD.Added full traceback to the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
on_release: self.output_csv(self.filepath2)
```

self means that you are calling function from Button class, and there's no function called output_csv, so error tells you that. You defined that function in the SyllWindow class. If that button is also on that screen, just change it to

```
on_release: root.output_csv(root.filepath)
```

Comment: Yes, the button is in the .kv's `<SyllWindow>`.

Comment: @Gavrk where's your filepath2 variable defined?

Comment: I changed it to `filepath` (defined by `filepath = args[1][0]`), so accordingly the Button's `on release` is now `root.output_csv(self.filepath)`. `filepath2` was excessive, since `root.output_csv(self.filepath)` can recognize `filepath`. It was my fault to put it in the original description, sorry for puzzling you. The error is now `AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'filepath'`

Comment: @Gavrk Try to use also root instead of self, I changed my answer, check it again.

Comment: Yep, just tried it out already. If I use `on_release: root.output_csv(root.filepath)` then the error is `'SyllWindow' object has no attribute 'filepath'`

Comment: @Gavrk instead of 'filepath' name in SyllWindow class use self.filepath everywhere. But don't change kv file.

Comment: Then the error is `TypeError: output_csv() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`, what's weird because `root.filepath` what was given is actually one argument, isn't it?

Comment: @Gavrk That's because of button, add to your function name *args, so it would be like: def output_csv(corpus_root, *args)

Comment: Well, then I get another error, but because of other reasons. This issue is cleared up! Thanks for your help and patience

Comment: May I know what kind of object is then `root.filepath`? The argument of the PlaintextCorpusReader was meant to be a string, but it seems to be some specific (two-component) object. How to extract string from that `root.filepath` from .kv file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207923/discussion-between-lothric-and-gavrk).